# Delete the old documents that i already copy

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to pass the documents that i have in a collection to another one, i already copy the documents in the old collection to the new one but now i dont know how to delete the old documents

For now i have this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection('shoplist')
          .get()
          .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(user.uid)
                      .collection('history')
                      .doc()
                      .set(result.data())
                      .then((value) => querySnapshot.docs.delete()); // Here is where i don't know what to do
                })
              });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to delete all documents in the `QuerySnapshot` in one call, which isn't possible. Instead, you should delete each document after you've written the copy, with:

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('history')
      .doc()
      .set(result.data())
      .then((value) => result.reference.delete()); //
```

Also note that you're current losing the original document ID in your copy. If your document IDs are meaningful, you want to maintain the document ID in the copy, and you only have one copy of each document, use:

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('history')
      .doc(result.id) // 
      .set(result.data())
      .then((value) => result.reference.delete());
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much for answering so quickly, I knew I was doing it wrong but I wanted to make a demonstration of what I wanted to do, thanks for the extra tip of the id too. You're incredible <3

Comment: Can you help me again please? i edit the post with a new doubt a got

Comment: This seems a different problem. Please remove it from this post (as it'll confuse future visitors who land here), and post a new question for it.

Comment: Sir, yes sir! :D